# RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, revisión-de-código

Tengo el siguiente programa transcrito en Python desde MATLAB

```
import numpy as np
from math import exp,ceil

def initial (x):
   init=0.09*np.exp(-x**2/50)
   return init


a = -20
b= 20
T=4
M=500
rhom=0.2
n=10
drho=rhom/n
rho=np.linspace(0,rhom,n+1)#lim inf, lim sup, "step"
def flux(rho):
    vf=15
    rhomax=0.2
    fl=vf*(1-rho/rhomax)*rho
    return fl

frho=flux(rho)   
qmax=max(frho)#Busca el máximo de la lista
s=np.argmax(frho)#devuelve el índice del valor máximo
rhostar=rho.item(s)#devuelce el elemento en la posicion "i"
#CFL Condition
lamda=max(abs(frho[1:n]-frho[0:n-1]))/drho
h=(b-a)/M
ka=0.5*h/lamda
N=ceil(T/ka)
k=T/N
#Inicializar:
kio=np.insert(np.arange(a+h/2,b-h/2,h),len(np.arange(a+h/2,b-h/2,h)),b-h/2)# np.insert(lista,length,valor_a_agragar)
xticks=kio.transpose()
U=np.zeros((M,N+1))
U[:,0]=initial(xticks)
for j in range(N):
  rhol=U[0:M-1,j-1]#U(1:M-1,j)
  rhor=U[1:M+1,j-1]#U(2:M,j)
  qval=flux(U[:,j-1])
  ql=qval[0:M-1]
  qr=qval[1:M+1]
  case1=(rhol<=rhor)
  case2=(rhol>rhostar)&(rhostar>rhor)
  case3= ~(case1|case2)
  Q1=np.sum(case1)*np.fmin(ql,qr)+np.sum(case2)*qmax+np.sum(case3)*np.fmax(ql,qr)
  Q2=np.insert(Q1,len(Q1),qval[M-1])
  Q=np.insert(Q2,0,flux(initial(a)))#np.insert("array","indice donde quiero que vaya el elemento","elemento")
  U[:,j+1]=U[:,j]+(k/h)*(Q[0:M]-Q[1:M+1])


print(U)
```

Al ejecutar el programa me sale lo siguiente

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 20
    fl=vf*(1-rho/rhomax)*rho
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 50
    U[:,j+1]=U[:,j]+(k/h)*(Q[0:M]-Q[1:M+1])
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in subtract

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 47
    Q1=np.sum(case1)*np.fmin(ql,qr)+np.sum(case2)*qmax+np.sum(case3)*np.fmax(ql,qr)
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 44
    case1=(rhol<=rhor)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less_equal

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 45
    case2=(rhol>rhostar)&(rhostar>rhor)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in greater

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 45
    case2=(rhol>rhostar)&(rhostar>rhor)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in less

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\ALEX EDUARDO\Documents\HolaMundoPython.py", line 47
    Q1=np.sum(case1)*np.fmin(ql,qr)+np.sum(case2)*qmax+np.sum(case3)*np.fmax(ql,qr)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
[[ 3.11723957e-05  4.79429950e-05 -8.85935460e-03 ...             nan
              nan             nan]
 [ 3.32241476e-05  3.32241476e-05 -5.52799370e-04 ...             nan
              nan             nan]
 [ 3.54018808e-05  3.54018808e-05 -5.86503957e-04 ...             nan
              nan             nan]
 ...
 [ 3.54018808e-05  3.54018808e-05  6.57307718e-04 ...             nan
              nan             nan]
 [ 3.32241476e-05  3.32241476e-05  6.19247665e-04 ...             nan
              nan             nan]
 [ 3.11723957e-05  3.11723957e-05  8.93792529e-03 ...             nan
              nan             nan]]
```

Y el resultado de la matriz U debería ser como en la imagen (MATLAB):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]